# run vlc without showing window

Tags: command-line, vlc

I'm using vlc to capture an image from my webcam by running the following command:

```
cvlc v4l2:///dev/webcam --no-audio --run-time 5 --scene-path $PWD \
    --scene-replace --scene-format png --video-filter scene vlc://quit
```

.  It works great except that I'm running this command in a cron job and it opens a player window for the duration of the capture, which gets in the way of me doing other stuff.  Is there any way to hide this window?  Can I tell vlc NOT to display this window whenever it runs?  I looked at the help docs but couldn't find anything relevant in there.

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-Vdummy`, the solution mentioned in the [previous answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/229699/1165986), seems to have been replaced by `-Idummy`  See [here](https://wiki.videolan.org/MacOS/#clivlc).

Comment: You are answering a over 10 year old question. Of course things have changed. I suggest ancient questions like this are not ones that need new answers.

Comment: new answers to old questions are perfectly acceptable and are preferable to duplicates each with frustratingly out-of-date answers.  I've updated this question to mark this answer as the accepted one.  thanks @hopefullyhelpful.

Comment: @DanO and hopefullyhelpful, I see that -Idummy is a MacOS flag.  I don't see any reference to -Idummy in the Linux VLC CLI help documentation.  Did you actually test out this flag and found it works?

Comment: @David please read https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/125967/278859. StackExchange is not a normal "forum" and thus **encourages** answering old questions.

Answer (score 6):

turns out there's a dummy interface command-line flag, `-Vdummy` , which does the trick.  Never mind!

Comment: This solution appears to no longer work.